# How to test external browser pages on electron application using testcafe

Tags: vue.js, testing, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm currently doing E2E testing using testcafe on an electron-vue application. In my authentification phase, I connect to another external application :enter username and password to authenticate. The problem is that I cannot apply test case on the external browser nor recuperate inputs from the external browser. Any suggestions( The external page is triggered via a Vue component button using open method)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, TestCafe can run a test in a single browser window only. Take a look at the [Mocking HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html) functionality. By using it, you can mock requests to and responses from the external application to avoid an external browser window opening.

Comment: thank yo for your help.But I think I can't mock this request because it's not beeing showen in the network of my electron application.Also, this login API contains a lot of informations being used to validate the login request and connect with the server(transmitted in the url).